# Are Employer pension plan and EI contributions necessary in Canada?

Tags: contracts, canada, employment, employment-agreement, insurance

Is it alright that there is no mention of Canada pension plan and EI contributions in an employment contract or in the letter of employment offer? Do these happen automatically at predefined rates and thus do not need to be mentioned in those documents?

Comment: What have your google searches yielded so far?

Comment: Are you being hired as an employee, or engaged as an independent contractor? If you are expecting to be an employee, you should make sure that's their expectation as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Employment Insurance and Canada Pension Plan (or Quebec Pension Plan if you are in Quebec) are deducted from your paycheck by law. Neither you nor your employer have any say in the matter and so there is no need for it to be stated in your contract.